# Why is the ObjectSecurity property in the DirectoryEntry instance of a GroupPrincipal always null?

Tags: c#, directoryentry, groupprincipal

I am trying to learn how to create a new Windows group (using C#) and assign an AccessRule to it by using the local user/group directory services.

I have written the following code which is attempting to firstly create the group, obtain the DirectoryEntry for it, and then creating and assigning a new custom AccessRule:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

...
...

var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, "groupName");
if (group == null)
{
    group = new GroupPrincipal(principalContext)
    {
        Name = "groupName",
        GroupScope = GroupScope.Local,
        Description = "groupName description",
        SamAccountName = "groupName",
    };

    group.Save();
}

var path = $"WinNT://{Environment.MachineName}/groupName,group";
var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path);

var accessRule = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(
    group.Sid,
    ActiveDirectoryRights.WriteProperty,
    AccessControlType.Allow,
    PermissionsDataSource.CanOverrideExpiredKeysPermissionId,
    ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance.None);

directoryEntry.ObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule(accessRule);
directoryEntry.Options.SecurityMasks = SecurityMasks.Dacl;

directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```

The line that is causing me problems at the moment is the following which attempts to add the newly created access rule to the security objects:

> ```
> directoryEntry.ObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule(accessRule);
> ```

The ObjectSecurity property is null. Similarly, the Options property is null. I am therefore not convinced I am creating the GroupPrincipal correctly.

It would be amazing if someone with some experience or knowledge in this area could help me understand what I need to do to be able to add access rules to the group object like I am trying to do above.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. The value

```
PermissionsDataSource.CanOverrideExpiredKeysPermissionId
```

is simply an arbitrary Guid which relates to the specific unique permission mapping that the application I am writing uses when checking if the groups a user belongs to has an access rule with this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're working with a local group. Local Windows groups don't have permissions.

You can see this by opening Computer Management (compmgmt.msc) -> Local Users and Groups -> Groups. Right-click on a group and click Properties. You'll see there is no Security tab.